# Finding the inverse Laplace transform of $\arctan \left(\frac{1}{s} \right)$using contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, contour-integration

Using contour integration, I want to show that $$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{\text{arctan} \left(\frac{1}{s}\right) \right\}(x)= \frac{\sin x }{x}.$$

In other words, I want to show that $$ \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{a - i \infty}^{a + i \infty} \text{arctan}\left(\frac{1}{s}\right) e^{xs} \ ds =\frac{\sin x}{x} ,$$ where $a$ is a constant greater than the real parts of all the singularities of $\text{arctan}\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)$.

We can define $\arctan \left(\frac{1}{s} \right)$ in terms of the complex logarithm.

Specifically, $$\arctan \left(\frac{1}{s} \right) = \frac{i}{2} \left[\log\left(1-\frac{i}{s}\right) - \log \left(1+\frac{i}{s}\right) \right]. $$

If we use the principal branch of the logarithm, then we need a branch cut on the imaginary axis from $-i$ to $i$.

I don't understand how to close contour.

Comment: Why do you want to show that by contour integration? It is much easier if you apply Laplace transform to $\frac{\sin t}{t}$.

Comment: Because we learn a lot about the structure of the function by working the inverse out directly.

Comment: I see why contour integration is useful in obtaining inverse Laplace transform, but for this particular problem, using contour integration will be difficult. On the other hand, using Laplace transform directly to $\frac{\sin t}{t}$ is almost immediate.

Comment: That's precisely how you evaluate that integral; see this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329347/how-to-calculate-int-01-arcsinx-sin-frac-pi2xdx/329355#329355

Comment: You need to be very careful about how you derive your result.  It's presumptive to just say that the ILT is equal to the integrals along those segments.  A better way of expressing this is to say that the integral about the contour is zero by Cauchy's theorem.  This forces you to get the signs right and not just put in a branch cut that gives you the right sign.  But that said, I might buy it.

Comment: I thought it was clear that I was making a big assumption.  What exactly do you mean by "putting in a branch cut that gives you the right sign?"

Comment: All I am saying is that you need to justify the signs you use by citing Cauchy's integral theorem.  I didn't say you weren't clear or wrong.  Just that, in forming the closed loop, you get the signs of the integrals relative to the original ILT.  That's all.

Comment: Don't we really just need to check the the integral goes to $0$ around those two little semi-circles about the branch points?

Comment: It does; you can literally eyeball it.  If you have seen my work here in evaluating contour integrals, I really have thrown out these steps unless there is a serious question about convergence.  (Usually this happens in using contour techniques in evaluating Fourier Transforms).

Comment: What's the indication that the singularities are weak and won't present a problem?

Comment: Just sub $z=\pm i + \epsilon e^{i \phi}$ and watch the behavior of the integral as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.  In this case, it should be clear to one who has done a gajillion series expansions that the integral vanishes as $\sqrt{\epsilon}$.  (If it diverges in this limit, then something is very wrong.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't worked out the integral along the contour yet, but here's a contour I had in mind:

[image]

This is definitely a sticky one.

Comment: I was wondering how the cut could be surrounded but not enclosed inside of the contour. I often have a hard time visualizing stuff. So the integral along six parts of that contour go to zero in the limit, and you're left with the integral from $-i$ to $i$ just to the right of the cut and the integral from $i$ to $-i$ just to left of the cut?

Comment: I take that back.  The integrals above and below the negative real axis cancel each other since there is no cut along that axis.

Comment: @RandomVariable: yes, you're right - no branch points along the neg. real axis, so the contributions cancel, I expect.  The contributions should come from the vertical sections adjoining the branch cut.

Comment: @RandomVariable: help me a little with that...

Comment: I need to stew over this some.  It may be a few days, but I will stew.

Comment: I think something that would use the same contour but might be a bit easier to deal with is the inverse Laplace transform of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{s^{2}+1}}$.

Comment: Good point!  Let me work on that one...still may be a while (have a day job and all).

Answer (score 3):

The following answer uses the contour provided above by Ron Gordon.

---

From the Maclaurin series of $\arctan(s)$, we can deduce that $\arctan \left(\frac{1}{s} \right) \sim \frac{1}{s}$ as $|s| \to \infty$.

We can then use a [modified version of Jordan's lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1658541) to conclude that $\int \arctan \left(\frac{1}{s} \right) e^{xs} \, ds$ vanishes along the two big arcs of the contour as the radii of the arcs go to infinity.

Also, since $\lim_{s \to \pm i} (s \mp i) \arctan \left( \frac{1}{s}\right)=0$, we get no contributions from letting the radii of the small circles about the branch points go to zero.

Moving clockwise around the branch point at  $s=1$, the value of $\arctan \left( \frac{1}{s} \right)$ increases by $\pi$.

And moving clockwise around the branch point at $s=-i$, the value of $\arctan \left(\frac{1}{s} \right)$ decreases by $\pi$.

Therefore, $$\begin{align} \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{\arctan \left(\frac{1}{s} \right) \right\}(x)  &= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int^{a+ i \infty}_{a - i \infty} \arctan \left(\frac{1}{s} \right) e^{xs} \, ds  \\ &= - \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \left(\pi \int_{1}^{0} e^{ixt} \, i \, dt  - \pi \int_{-1}^{0} e^{ixt} \, i \,  dt \right) \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} e^{ixt} \, dt \\ &= \frac{1}{2ix} \left(e^{ix} - e^{-ix} \right) \\ &= \frac{\sin(x)}{x}. \end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}
^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}\arctan\pars{1 \over s}\expo{st}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}} =
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}
^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}
{s\expo{st} \over s^{2} + x^{2}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{{-\ic x\expo{-\ic tx} \over -\ic x - \ic x} +
{\ic x\expo{-\ic tx} \over \ic x + \ic x}}\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}\cos\pars{tx}\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\ \bbx{\ds{\sin\pars{t} \over t}} \\ &
\end{align}