# A question about Jordan Lemma and estimation Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, estimation

> Let $|F(z)|\leq \frac{M}{R^k}$ for some positive numbers $M$ and $k$, where $z=Re^{i\theta}$. Prove that
>
> $$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{|z|=R,\:\mathcal{R}(z)\geq0}e^{imz}F(z)\,dz=0$$
>
> for any constant $m>0$.

The only thing I could think is using Jordan Lemma which I'm not sure how. Is it possible that the question be wrong? I appreciate any hint.

It's very similar to [Proving a modified version of Jordan's lemma?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657849/proving-a-modified-version-of-jordans-lemma?rq=1). However here we have $e^{imz}$ instead of $e^{mz}$, which in this case, I couldn't prove it.

Comment: The integral should be over $\lvert z\rvert = R$, and $\operatorname{Im} z \geqslant 0$. Then it's just Jordan's lemma. Since $\lvert e^{imz}\rvert = e^{-m\operatorname{Im} z}$, the integrand becomes large on the lower half-plane, and usually there isn't cancellation making that part tend to $0$ as $R \to \infty$.

Comment: This was something that I thought during my test, but I said it's impossible to have a such a type on the test. :(

Comment: There have been, and in future will be, more embarrassing typos in tests and in textbooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time i will show a counter example that fully satisfy your hypothesis, but not the thesis. The main idea is the same of my previous answer. Please, correct me if wrong.

**step 1** The real function $ \displaystyle f(x) = \frac{e^{-mx}}{x}$  is summable over $\mathbb{R^+}$ but not summable over $\mathbb{R^-}$, hence
$$
  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-mx}}{x} \; dx = - \infty
$$

**step 2** the complex function $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ is such that $\displaystyle |f(R e^{i \theta})| = \frac{1}{R}$.

**step 3** We define four curves for $R > 1$
$$
 \sigma_{1,R} : \left[ \frac{1}{R}, R  \right] \to \mathbb{C} \qquad \sigma_{1,R}(t) = it
\qquad
\qquad
 \sigma_{2,R} : \left[ -R, -\frac{1}{R} \right] \to \mathbb{C} \qquad \sigma_{2,R}(t) = it
$$
$$
 C_{1,R}: \left[ -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right] \to \mathbb{C} \qquad C_{1,R}(t) = R e^{it}
\qquad \qquad
C_{2,R}: \left[ -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right] \to \mathbb{C} \qquad C_{2,R}(t) = \frac{e^{it}}{R}
$$
To visualize it, the composition of this four path (noticing that $\sigma_{1,R}$ and $\sigma_{2,R}$ need to be reversed) is the boundary of a half donut

**step 4** We now compute the integral of $\displaystyle \frac{e^{imz}}{z}$ over $\sigma_{1,R}, \sigma_{2,R}$ and $C_{2,R}$:
$$
  \int_{\sigma_{1,R}} \frac{e^{imz}}{z} \; dz = \int_{1/R}^R \frac{e^{-mt}}{t} dt
\qquad \qquad
  \int_{\sigma_{2,R}} \frac{e^{imz}}{z} \; dz = \int_{-R}^{-1/R} \frac{e^{-mt}}{t} dt
$$
Thus the limit
$$
  \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{\sigma_{1,R}} \frac{e^{imz}}{z} \; dz + \int_{\sigma_{2,R}} \frac{e^{imz}}{z} \; dz = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-mt}}{t} \; dt = \infty
$$
Where $\infty$ is the complex compactification infinity. The other integral instead, by the small circle lemma - (if you need clarification i can explicitly prove it) is such that
$$
\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{C_{2,R}} \frac{e^{imz}}{z} \; dz = i \pi
$$

**step 4**
Noticing that the composition of the aforementioned paths describe the boundary of a domain $D$ not containing $0$, the function $\displaystyle \frac{e^{imz}}{z}$ is olomorphic in this domain and in particular the integral over $\partial D$ is zero by the cauchy's integral theorem. Hence

$$
  \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{C_{1,R}} \frac{e^{imz}}{z} \; dz = \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{\sigma_{1,R}} \frac{e^{imz}}{z} \; dz + \int_{\sigma_{2,R}} \frac{e^{imz}}{z} \; dz + \int_{C_{2,R}} \frac{e^{imz}}{z} \; dz
= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-mt}}{t} \; dt + i \pi = \infty
$$

In particular the LHS cannot be zero

Answer (score 2):

I think that the following should be a counter example. I will build it in steps

1. The real function $\frac{ e^{-mx}}{x^2 + 1}$ is continuos and positive but not summable. So
   $$ 
   \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{ e^{-mx} }{x^2 + 1} \; dx = +\infty
   $$
2. The complex function $f(z) = \frac{1}{1 - z^2}$ has modulus smaller than $\frac{2}{|z|^2}$ for large enough $|z|$
3. Due to Residue theorem, since the function $\frac{e^{imz}}{1-z^2}$ has only one simple pole in the right half disk of radius R > 1, that is $1$ with residue $\frac{e^{im}}{2}$ , denoting with $\sigma_R$ the curve
   $$
      \sigma_R : [-R,R] \quad
      \sigma_R(t) = it
   $$
   then
   $$
   \int_{|z|=R, \Re(z) > 0} e^{imz} f(z) \; dz - \int_{\sigma_R} e^{imz} f(z)\; dz = 2\pi i \frac{e^{im}}{2}
   $$

$$
 \int_{|z|=R, \Re(z) > 0} e^{imz} f(z) \; dz =  \pi e^{im} + \int_{\sigma_R} e^{imz} f(z) \; dz = i \int_{-R}^R \frac{e^{-mt}}{1 + t^2} \; dt
$$

Point 1 and 3 togheter imply that the limit does not go to zero, while point 2 guarantee that all the hypothesis are satisfied

Comment: This is a very nice counterexample, thank you! I would still like to keep the question open to find out about alternative counterexamples and possible solutions.

Comment: The second part is only true for larger value of $|z|$, but the question hypothesis states it should be true for all $z=Re^{i\theta}$. But I think it's very close.