# $PV \int_{ia-\infty}^{ia+\infty}\frac{e^{ikt}}{\sqrt{t^2-b^2}}dt$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

How would I calculate

\begin{align}
PV \int_{ia-\infty}^{ia+\infty}\frac{e^{ikt}}{\sqrt{t^2-b^2}}dt
\end{align}

The square root should be dealt with as is most appropriate, e.g. by taking a branch cut from $t=-b$ to $t=+b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the $PV$.  Assume $k, b \gt 0$ and $a \lt 0$.  Consider

$$\oint_C dz \frac{e^{i k z}}{\sqrt{z^2-b^2}} $$

where $C$ consists of a number of segments:

$$C_1 = \{ z = i a + t | t \in [-R,R] \} $$
$$C_2 = \{ z = R e^{i \theta} | \theta \in [0,\pi] \}$$
$$C_3 = \{ z = -b+\epsilon e^{i \phi} | \phi \in (0, 2 \pi) \} $$
$$C_4 = \{ z = x + i \delta | x \in [-b+\epsilon,b-\epsilon] \} $$
$$C_5 = \{ z = b+\epsilon e^{i \phi} | \phi \in (-\pi, \pi) \} $$
$$C_6 = \{ z = x - i \delta | x \in [-b+\epsilon,b-\epsilon] \} $$

where $\delta \gt 0$ depends on $\epsilon$ and goes to zero with $\epsilon$.

We are interested in the limits as $R \to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0$.  In these limits, the integral vanishes over $C_2$, $C_4$, and $C_6$.  The result is, for the contour integral,

$$\int_{i a -\infty}^{i a + \infty} dt \frac{e^{i k t}}{\sqrt{t^2-b^2}} - i \int_b^{-b} dx \frac{e^{i k x}}{\sqrt{b^2-x^2}} + i \int_{-b}^b dx \frac{e^{i k x}}{\sqrt{b^2-x^2}}$$

A little explanation.  On $C_4$, $\arg{(x+b)} = 0$ and $\arg{(x-b)} = \pi$.  However, on $C_6$, $\arg{(x+b)} = 0$ and $\arg{(x-b)} = -\pi$.  Thus, because the contour integral is zero by Cauchy's theorem,

$$\int_{i a -\infty}^{i a + \infty} dt \frac{e^{i k t}}{\sqrt{t^2-b^2}} = -i 2 \int_{-b}^b dx \frac{e^{i k x}}{\sqrt{b^2-x^2}} = -i 2 \pi J_0(b k)$$

The above assumed that $k \gt 0$.  When $k \lt 0$, the integral on the left is zero because there are no poles or branch points of the integrand in the region $\operatorname{Im}{z} \lt a$.

When $a \gt 0$, reverse the sign of $k$ in the above results.  Putting this altogether, we finally have

$$\int_{i a -\infty}^{i a + \infty} dt \frac{e^{i k t}}{\sqrt{t^2-b^2}} = i 2 \pi \operatorname{sgn}{(a)} J_0(b k) H\left [-k \operatorname{sgn}{(a)} \right ]$$

where $H$ is the Heaviside step function.

N.B. Proof of the Bessel integral may be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329347/how-to-calculate-int-01-arcsinx-sin-frac-pi2xdx/329355#329355).  Also, I realize that $C$ as defined is not exactly closed.  The pieces that would connect $C_1$ and $C_2$ vanish as $R \to \infty$, so I did not bother to include them.  I will expound on this in more detail in a future post, as I have yet to see a clear demonstration of this simple, yet essential fact, in the textbooks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I don't quite see how your $C$ forms a closed contour in the argand plane. $C_3,C_4,C_5,C_6$ all seem to form a closed loop around the poles of the integrand, but how are then $C_1$ and $C_2$ connected? Sorry if I missed something obvious.

Comment: Imagine a pair of line segments connecting $C_1$ to $C_4$, so that you double up and back along it.  The integral along those line segments, up and back, is zero, so we can just imagine the contour having two disconnected pieces like this.  BTW this is how the residue theorem is proven.

Comment: Oh, and you noticed a sleight of hand.  I ignored the little pieces that would connect $C_1$ and $C_2$.  Those pieces may be shown to vanish as $R \to \infty$ just as the integral vanishes along $C_2$.  I hate to give away something I plan to blog about soon, but there you have it.

Comment: Ok great! So one of these would be $C_7 = \{z=R+ix | x \in (0,a)\}$? I will start to follow your blog, you have some great material there.

Comment: @Jack: thanks.  Not quite - although in figures I draw it that way.  I'd rather prove it by defining $C_7$ and $C_8$ as continuations of $C_2$ to $C_1$.  This means that the endpoints of $C_1$ are not $\pm R$ but are rather $\pm \sqrt{R^2-a^2}$.  In the limit as $R \to \infty$, who cares, but this is the sort of detail you need to prove that the arcs do not contribute to the contour integral.

Comment: That makes sense. And then for the connecting line between say $C_1$ and $C_6$ I could just draw a double thick vertical line connecting them?

Comment: @Jack: something like that.  Call the pair $C_9$ and $C_{10}$ if you want.

Comment: Sorry, there is actually one thing I still don't understand. Why does the sign of $k$ determine if there are poles or branch points of the integrand?

Comment: Because it is not valid to use the contour $C_2$ when $k$ is the wrong sign, as the integral over that piece would diverge.  So we need to flip the direction of the contour, from up to down, or vice versa, and in that case there are no poles or branch points.  This the integral is zero there.